# How to filter modded servers in the server browser?

Tags: source-engine

No Valve games had official servers and automatic matchmaking prior to Team Fortress 2 (may have been added in updates) to my knowledge. It's possible to disable downloading custom files in multiplayer settings, but this only prevents you from connecting to a server running a custom map, not to a server running mods (the infamous ["ERROR" sign](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Missing_content) is displayed if any custom textures are in use)! For instance in Day of Defeat: Source, "parachute" and "medic" mods are commonly used on active servers — essentially tweaking the gameplay based on the host's preferences. I'm not aware of a way to filter or even mark the servers in the browser, the only method I know is to always check if the server is running an official map. "Tags" can be used to inform players about mods, but I don't know if any are automatically added to a modded server.

[image: "ERROR"]

Comment: Tags are only automatic for things built into the game; for example, Team Fortress 2 sets a tag depending on what game mode is being used.

Comment: @Powerlord: So all custom tags are optional? Also, could you as the server host intentionally use misleading tags (even if the server isn't running any mods)?

Comment: Yes, custom tags are optional and servers can use misleading tags.  There are only a few tags (which vary by game) that the server will remove if a server operator tries to manually set them.